# (Open Source) Examples of JavaScript Prototypical OO

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypal-inheritance, ecmascript-5, prototypal

**Bounty Edit:**

I'm looking for code written in a *pure* prototypical OO paradigm (think Self). Not a mixture of prototypical OO and classical OO. I don't want to see generic OO wrappers but simply usage of prototypical OO techniques and *only* prototypical OO techniques.

**Reference Related Question:**

[Prototypical OO in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526241/prototypical-oo-in-javascript)

In the above question I mainly focused on

> Can write prototypical OO like this?
>
> Do we need constructors and initialization logic, What are the alternatives?

**New question:**

Basically are there any *good examples of javascript prototypical* OO in large open source projects?

**Clarification:**

I will have to clarify what I mean with **prototypical OO** :

- There are no classes. There are only Objects.
- **There is *zero* emulation of the concepts of classes,** again there is only objects and cloning objects to create new objects.

**Further Clarification of Prototypical OO:**

The difference between prototypical OO in JavaScript and classical OO emulation is a *very grey area*. It's not that I *value* avoiding classical OO. I want to learn prototypical OO in an academic fashion in it's own right, without learning the (probably more optimum) combination of classical OO emulation and prototypical OO.

This is why I "ban" classes, just so that I can see these techniques in a pure fashion and extend my own OO tool kit.

**Examples:**

Popular examples like jQuery fail to meet the second criteria. The `jQuery` object is one big class emulation. It focuses on creating new objects from a class rather then cloning existing objects.

If I actually knew any example of using *"pure"* prototypical OO I would have shown you. I believe 99% of JavaScript OO is too heavily influenced by classical emulation.

**Bonus points**

If

- It's well comented / documented
- Has unit tests
- Is on github.

I will also accept articles / tutorials and examples on how to write prototypical OO code that goes beyond your trivial hello world application.

Comment: I read your previous q yesterday and the discussion, and I am very interested in this discussion. But I still don't understand something fundamental here. Why do you consider adding methods to a "class" to be impure? What exactly is the distinction you are seeking between prototypical and class-based OO? Cloning an object and adding new methods/members is part of the design of the prototype construct. Just because this happens to be functonally similar to class-based inheritance, why isn't this a legitimate part of a "prototypical" design? What benefits do you seek by avoiding this construct?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at this : http://plugins.jquery.com/project/classBuilder This is not exactly what your are looking for, and thus not an answer, but still interesting in the current topic.

Comment: @jamietre the distinction is very very _grey_ and I see that it's a problem. The problem lies in that I know classical OO. It's not a matter of wanting to avoid classical OO but rather a matter of wanting to learn prototypical OO (without spending a few weeks learning Self). The main problem lies that there is very little academic information on _pure_ prototyical OO in JavaScript. I hope the edit to the question clarifies this. I seek to learn pure concepts so I can combine them together with current OO techniques properly.

Comment: @deadalnix Although an interesting read, that is a solid example of what I'm _not_ looking for. I want to move away from any form of "class emulation".

Comment: I don't see why jQuery is a bad example here (at least your argument does not seem to be valid to me). Adding a method to `jQuery.fn` is not related to classical OO at all. Clearly the features of prototypal inheritance are used here to make this work (adding a method and every (also previously) created objects inherit it). But maybe I'm not getting the point. To be frank, I did not read your previous question completely.

Comment: @FelixKling the jQuery.fn argument was false, I removed it. Thanks. The difference is that jQuery has the concept of classes and objects just like most js OO. The thing I want to avoid is the concept of class, and that's very difficult to avoid as the vast majority of js developers have this concept. I'm looking to give alternatives a _try_. I'm not saying that class is bad or that it should be done differently.

Comment: OK, I see. I assume you've read the wikipedia article (which I read yesterday for the first time) e.g. concatenation vs. delegation. Javascript can do both. The only truly functional difference that I see from class design is the ability to change a method *that affects all existing copies* under a "delegation" design, in js, that would mean altering the `prototype` of an existing method. But according to wiki this is "impure." So if 
"concatenation" is pure, how does it differ functionally from class-based method overriding?

Comment: @jamietre I don't actually know. I want to learn prototypical OO by example from reputable code. I have zero knowledge of high level architecture and design for "pure" prototypical OO, hence I'm asking for examples.

Comment: @Raynos I have a framework. But I do not know if it fits your requirements. because you want  **zero emulation of the concepts of classes**. And those bolded words are very vague indeed. it's hard to understand what you want unless u define what you mean by a **class**. So is an "interface" a class?

Comment: @Pacerier an interface is not a class, an interface is a definition of an object. A programmatic concept of interfaces probably falls under class emulation. Interfaces should exist in documentation and in your head.

Comment: Find a traditional object model, then implement it using the prototype model. I cant think of a better way of finding out if it works.

Comment: @Raynos then your definition of an interface is the same as the definition of a class: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/class. anyways, take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will not find it.

I went looking for this sort of thing a while ago, and this is what I found: the [Self Paper *Organizing Programs Without Classes*](http://labs.oracle.com/self/papers/organizing-programs.html) (Look at [Citeseer for a PDF version](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.56.8715).) This paper discusses the best practices for *Self*, the original prototypal language, and the best practice is to use the "traits object idiom", which is to have your objects inherit from "traits objects" that contain only methods, and no object specific data. In other words, an object that is suspiciously like a class.

Even the original prototypal language emulates classes.

Comment: There has to be a whole bunch of academic data. I already know that honestly I need to dig into research and academia around Self. I was hoping some large industry projects have used the theory. There is _so_ much code out there, Surely someone has written code like this.

Answer (score 4):

Have you taken a look at OMeta/JS? OMeta is an experimental research pattern matching language based on Smalltalk and Self. OMeta/JS is an implementation in javascript using prototypical OO.

It is well commented and documented with many examples. It is also on Github.

http://tinlizzie.org/ometa-js/

https://github.com/alexwarth/ometa-js

Edit: OMeta is the result of Alexander Warth's PhD disertation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for, but my current framework allows you to program in OO fashion like so:

```
Cin.define({
    name: 'MyApp.Logger',
    extends: 'Cin.Component',
    implements: ['MyApp.ILogger'],
    mixes: {
        SomeMixin: 'MyApp.SomeMixin'
    },

    init: function() {
    },

    method: function() {
    },

    statics: {
        staticMethod: function() {}
    }
});
```

And then you can write code like:

```
var instance = new MyApp.Logger();
instance.method();

MyApp.Logger.staticMethod();
```

I am not trying to *emulate* classical OO here. I am trying to make a convenient and useful way to declare inheritance, mixins, interfaces, and general OO concepts so that it becomes easy for the developer to write such OO code. This also gives me the chance to finish my auto loading component so that you no longer take care of dependencies and you can make custom builds and enjoy faster development thanks to not needing to load 100 scripts per each page load.

If you want to learn prototypical OO concepts, I think you should write some kind of inheritance system. Take a look at [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/) or [ExtJS](http://extjs.com). A good thing to remember is that Prototype-based systems twist and mangle, they are more powerful than Class-based OO languages. In my opinion, there is no single right way to write prototypal code.

I'm afraid though that most if not all inheritance systems might look like they emulate classical OO. In my opinion, my framework does not, but then it's not even finished.

Comment: Although I appreciate the information and the answer. It still fails criteria 2 by having the concept of a class and instances. Even though your not tyring to emulate classical OO your OO system is still _based_ on it. So it does not actually answer the question, I dont want to write an inheritance system like Dojo and ExtJS, those are still far too class based. They are _not_ object based.

Comment: @Raynos what do you mean by having the concept of a class? In my framework you create _Types_. It's an object which represents a specific type of an object. Then you create new objects which have the Type in their prototype. That's purely prototypal to me. You can even do `instance.changeType('MyApp.AnotherType')` in my framework to switch types on the fly. I fail to see how this is classical because it's not even possible in classical OO. The same applies to other features such as `instance.addMixin()`. Those concepts do not exist in classical OO.

Comment: you make some valid points, I take back that your code has a class. It's still not what I'm looking for. I'm looking _not_ for a generic OO abstraction, I'm looking for examples of using prototypical OO directly without going through a black box abstraction. I still think your implementation is a combination of both patterns and not "pure" but that's subjective.

Comment: it would really help if you showed the source code. I made a rash judgement and I should at least inspect the code of `define`

Answer (score 1):

Probably [JSLint](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint) (Crockford's a proponent of prototypical inheritance, but I haven't combed through every inch of it).  It's also looks more functional than Object Oriented, but then I expect that's generally the case with code that truly embraces prototypical inheritance.

Comment: Perhaps not.  Line 1195:  return new F();  However, it's the implementation of his Object.create method, which he uses to remove the use of constructors throughout the rest of the code.  var someObject = Object.create(someOtherObject); where someObject now inherits from someOtherObject.  But strictly speaking, this disqualifies it.

Comment: Well he is just emulating ES5 Object.create for older browsers. His emulation of it doesnt meet the ES5 spec but it if it's used like the ES5 spec then it's probably not disqualified.

Answer (score 1):

In my framework, everything is an object or an "interface".

Interfaces define the common functions (methods / property_gets / property_sets) that objects may have.

You create an interface like this: `var some_interface = GetInterface(constructor, interface_setup, parent_interface..)`

You can specify any number of parent_interfaces. So if `interface_A` inherits both `interface_B` and `interface_C`, you can create interface_A as such: `GetInterface(constructor, interface_setup, interface_B, interface_C);`

If `interface_A` inherits `interface_X` and `interface_X` inherits `interface_Y`, then `interface_A` will have all the functions which both `interface_X` and `interface_Y` has.

Interfaces which do not require a constructor will leave the constructor argument as null. The interface_setup is a function which looks like this:

```
function(proto){
}
```

The object that the *proto* argument points to has 4 methods: `SetM`, `ShadowM`, `SetP`, and `ShadowP`.

You use these 4 methods to *setup* your interface.

This framework also provides lazy instantiation of interfaces. (in other words the setup code will never actually be ran until it is actually first needed).

Limitations of this framework requires at least support for `Object.keys`, `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` and `Object.defineProperty`. (In other words it works in the latest versions of FireFox, IE, Chrome, Safari but not Opera)

**TestPage2.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<script src="js.js"></script>
<script>
var human = GetInterface(function(){
},function(proto){
    //alert("trace: initing human");
    proto.$SetM("Sleep",function(){
        alert(this.Name+" is sleeping");
    });
    proto.$SetP("Name",function(){
        return this._name;
    },function(value){
        this._name=value;
    });
});

var female = GetInterface(function(){
},function(proto){
    //alert("trace: initing female");
    proto.$SetM("Dance",function(){
        alert(this.Name+" is dancing");
    });
},human);

var male = GetInterface(function(){
},function(proto){
    //alert("trace: initing male");
    proto.$SetM("Fight",function(){
        alert(this.Name+" is fighting");
    });
    proto.$ShadowP("Name",function(parent_get){
        return "Mr. "+parent_get();
    },function(parent_set,value){
        parent_set(value);
    });
},human);

var child = GetInterface(function(){
},function(proto){
    //alert("trace: initing child");
    proto.$SetM("Play",function(){
        alert(this.Name+" is playing");
    });
},human);

var adult = GetInterface(function(){
},function(proto){
    //alert("trace: initing adult");
    proto.$SetM("Work",function(){
        alert(this.Name+" is working");
    });
},human);

var mammal = GetInterface(function(){
},function(proto){
    //alert("trace: initing mammal");
    proto.$SetM("DoMammalStuff",function(){
        alert("doing mammal stuff");
    });
});


var john=new male();
john.Name="john";
john.Sleep();

var mary=new female();
mary.$IsA(child);
mary.$IsA(mammal);
mary.$Setup(function(proto){
    proto.$ShadowP("Name",function(parent_get){
        return "Miss "+parent_get.call(this);
    },function(parent_set,value){
        parent_set.call(this,value);
    });
});
mary.Name="mary";
mary.Play();
</script>
```

**TestPage.html:**

```
 <!doctype html>
<script src="js.js"></script>
<script>
var human_interface = GetInterface(function(){
},function(proto){
    alert("trace: initing human");
    proto.$SetM("Sleep",function(){
        alert(this.Name+" is sleeping");
    });
    proto.$SetP("Name",function(){
        return this._name;
    },function(value){
        this._name=value;
    });
});

var female_interface = GetInterface(function(){
},function(proto){
    alert("trace: initing female");
    proto.$SetM("Dance",function(){
        alert(this.Name+" is dancing");
    });
},human_interface);

var male_interface = GetInterface(function(){
},function(proto){
    alert("trace: initing male");
    proto.$SetM("Fight",function(){
        alert(this.Name+" is fighting");
    });
},human_interface);

var child_interface = GetInterface(function(){
},function(proto){
    alert("trace: initing child");
    proto.$SetM("Play",function(){
        alert(this.Name+" is playing");
    });
},human_interface);

var adult_interface = GetInterface(function(){
},function(proto){
    alert("trace: initing adult");
    proto.$SetM("Work",function(){
        alert(this.Name+" is working");
    });
},human_interface);

var mammal_interface = GetInterface(function(){
},function(proto){
    alert("trace: initing mammal");
    proto.$SetM("DoMammalStuff",function(){
        alert("doing mammal stuff");
    });
});

var john={};
john.$IsA(adult_interface);
//the above 2 lines are equal to simply doing:
//var john=new adult_interface();
//you can think of it as a shortcut
john.$IsA(mammal_interface);
john.DoMammalStuff();
john.Name="john";
john.Sleep();

var mary=new female_interface();
mary.$IsA(child_interface);
mary.$IsA(mammal_interface);
mary.DoMammalStuff();
mary.Name="mary";
mary.Play();
mary.Dance();
</script>
```

**Js.js:**

```
"use strict";
var GetInterface;
(function(){
    //================================================================================//
    //(constructor:Function, setup:Function?, parent_interfaces:Function..):Function
    GetInterface = function (constructor, setup) {
        var parent_classes = GetParray(arguments, 2);
        var output = function () {
            output.$Init();
            for (var x = parent_classes.length - 1; x >= 0; --x) {
                parent_classes[x](this);
            }
            if(constructor===null){
                constructor.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        };
        output.$Init = Mize(function () {
            var output_proto = output.prototype;
            parent_classes.forEach(function (parent_class) {
                parent_class.$Init();
                Infect(output_proto, parent_class.prototype);
            });
            init_proto(output_proto,setup);
            if(setup!==undefined){
                setup(output_proto);
            }
        });
        return output;
    };
    var init_proto=function(proto){
        $defineProperty(proto, "$SetM", { value: set_m, writable: true, configurable: true });
        $defineProperty(proto, "$ShadowM", { value: shadow_m, writable: true, configurable: true });
        $defineProperty(proto, "$SetP", { value: set_p, writable: true, configurable: true });
        $defineProperty(proto, "$ShadowP", { value: shadow_p, writable: true, configurable: true });
    };
    var set_m = function (method_name, method) {
        this[method_name] = method;
    };
    var set_p = function (property_name, getter, setter) {
        $defineProperty(this, property_name, { get: getter, set: setter, enumerable: true, configurable: true });
    };
    var shadow_m = function (method_name, supplied_method) {
        var old_method = this[method_name];
        this[method_name] = function () {
            var args = GetParray(arguments);
            args.unshift(old_method.bind(this));
            supplied_method.apply(this, args);
        };
    };
    var shadow_p = function (property_name, getter, setter) {
        var old_descriptor = $getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, property_name);
        var old_get = old_descriptor.get;
        var old_set = old_descriptor.set;
        $defineProperty(this, property_name, { get: function () {
            return getter.call(this, old_get.bind(this));
        }, set: function (value) {
            setter.call(this, old_set.bind(this), value);
        }, enumerable: true, configurable: true
        });
    };
    var $slice=Array.prototype.slice;
    var $defineProperty=Object.defineProperty;
    var $getOwnPropertyDescriptor=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor;
    if($defineProperty===undefined){
        throw "Object.defineProperty, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor, Object.keys are required";
    }
    //================================================================================//
    //(victim:Object, disease:Object):void
    var Infect=function (victim, disease, excludes) {
        var keys=Object.keys(disease);
        if(excludes!==undefined){
            excludes.forEach(function(exclude){
                ForEach(keys,function(key,x){
                    if(key===exclude){
                        keys.splice(x,1);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        keys.forEach(function(key){
            $defineProperty(victim, key, $getOwnPropertyDescriptor(disease, key));
        });
    };
    //================================================================================//
    //(args:Object # arguments object #, start_index:int?):Array
    var GetParray = function (args, start_index) {
        if (start_index === undefined) {
            start_index = 0;
        }
        return $slice.call(args, start_index);
    };
    //================================================================================//
    //(array:Array, f:Function(item:Object|null, index:pint):boolean?):Object
    var ForEach=function(array,f){
        for (var x = 0, xx = array.length, last_index=xx-1; x < xx; ++x) {
            var result = f(array[x], x, last_index);
            if (result !== undefined) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    };
    //================================================================================//
    //provides memoization.
    //(f:Function, arity_fixed:boolean?true):Function
    //caching is done according to the inputs. the results of calling function(undefined) and function() are cached differently.
    //if arity is fixed, optimizations can be done
    var Mize=function(f, arity_fixed) {
        if (arity_fixed === undefined) {
            arity_fixed = true;
        }
        var used; //for 0 arg
        var result; //for 0 arg
        var results; //for >0 args
        var used_params; //for 1 arg
        var used_param_sets; //for >1 args
        var f_length = f.length;
        var use_generic = !arity_fixed || f_length > 3;
        if (use_generic) { //if `f_length` <= 3, it will be optimized (i.e. not using generic function)
            results = [];
            used_param_sets = [];
            return function () {
                var params = GetParray(arguments);
                var result_found = false;
                var result = ForEach(used_param_sets,function (used_param_set, x) {
                    if (used_param_set.length === params.length) {
                        var params_match = true;
                        ForEach(params,function (param, y) {
                            if (used_param_set[y] !== param) {
                                params_match = false;
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        if (params_match) {
                            result_found = true;
                            return results[x];
                        }
                    }
                });
                if (!result_found) {
                    used_param_sets.push(params);
                    result = f.apply(null, params);
                    results.push(result);
                }
                return result;
            };
        }
        if (f_length === 0) {
            used = false;
            return function () {
                if (!used) {
                    result = f();
                    used = true;
                }
                return result;
            };
        }
        if (f_length === 1) {
            used_params = [];
        } else {
            used_param_sets = [];
        }
        results = [];
        switch (f_length) {
            case 1:
                return function (arg) {
                    var result_found = false;
                    var result = ForEach(used_params,function (used_param, x) {
                        if (arg === used_param) {
                            result_found = true;
                            return results[x];
                        }
                    });
                    if (!result_found) {
                        used_params.push(arg);
                        result = f(arg);
                        results.push(result);
                    }
                    return result;
                };
                break;
            case 2:
                return function (arg1, arg2) {
                    var result_found = false;
                    var result = ForEach(used_param_sets,function (used_param_set, x) {
                        if (arg1 === used_param_set[0] && arg2 === used_param_set[1]) {
                            result_found = true;
                            return results[x];
                        }
                    });
                    if (!result_found) {
                        used_param_sets.push([arg1, arg2]);
                        result = f(arg1, arg2);
                        results.push(result);
                    }
                    return result;
                };
                break;
            case 3:
                return function (arg1, arg2, arg3) {
                    var result_found = false;
                    var result = ForEach(used_param_sets,function (used_param_set, x) {
                        if (arg1 === used_param_set[0] && arg2 === used_param_set[1] && arg3 === used_param_set[2]) {
                            result_found = true;
                            return results[x];
                        }
                    });
                    if (!result_found) {
                        used_param_sets.push([arg1, arg2, arg3]);
                        result = f(arg1, arg2, arg3);
                        results.push(result);
                    }
                    return result;
                };
                break;
            default:
                throw "Invalid `f_length`: " + f_length;
        }
    };
    //================================================================================//
    Object.prototype.$Setup=function(setup){
        setup(Object.getPrototypeOf(this));
    };
    //================================================================================//
    Object.prototype.$IsA=function(_interface){
        var excludes=GetParray(arguments,1);
        if(this.$SetM===undefined){
            this.$SetM=set_m;
            this.$SetP=set_p;
            this.$ShadowM=shadow_m;
            this.$ShadowP=shadow_p;
        }
        _interface.$Init();
        /*var this_proto={};
        init_proto(this_proto);
        Infect(this_proto,Object.getPrototypeOf(this));
        this.__proto__=this_proto;*/
        Infect(Object.getPrototypeOf(this),_interface.prototype,excludes);
    };
    //================================================================================//
})();
```

Comment: It's a good attempt. It's sticking to the prototypical idea but I don't like the abstraction. I think it's too limiting. I also don't like the concept of shadowing properties (feels really dirty) and I'd prefer the ability to add pre and post hooks to methods rather then shadowing them.

Comment: it's a very thin abstraction on `Object.create`  and `object.defineProperty` might aswell not have it.

Answer (score 0):

[ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/) is an excellent example of JavaScript OO. It implements a really sophisticated, enterprise-level OO hierarchy in JavaScript that does a lot of things out of the box. It may be a daunting read (last I checked in 3.X, it was over 1MB of raw, uncompressed JavaScript), but it'd give you a lot of ideas. You could start out by [reviewing the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/) to get a high-level view.

Comment: Not looking for that. fails criteria 2 because it emulates classical OO.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example showing the basis of the OO programming that you are looking for.  Best real-world example would be jQuery probably.

When learning JavaScript, you have to keep in mind that it is actually closer to Scheme than it is C or Java at its roots.  Basically it is Scheme in C's syntax.

There is almost never a case where you should use "new" in JavaScript, especially if you are writing APIs.  It seems as the "new" operator was added in because it JavaScript was not sure about its prototypal framework.  For most of us that start programming with classical languages such as C, C++, and Java, this seems odd, as "new" is generally exactly what we are looking for, because it translates easily.

Why shouldn't I use "new" you ask?  Well, due to the implementation of "new", you can inadvertently start wiping out your global data (which remember, is everything not in a function in JavaScript).  If you happen to fall prey to this, then you will not see any errors, or notifications, but only see unpredictable behavior in your program.  Also, it may or may not be clear as to what "this" actually is bound to within your "class".

The wipe out your global memory without knowing it problem mainly occurs when you write a function that is intended to be called with "new" and the user does not use "new".  Hints why using it in APIs can lead to unhappy users.

The correct way to object oriented "classes" and inheritance is to use JavaScript's most powerful attribute...the object.

You can write a function to return an object to establish a "class".  Anything you put into this object (numbers, strings, methods, etc.) are all public properties of your "class".  Anything you write within your function that is not inside that object that is being returned, is private.

To inherit from your "class", you can simply initialize your object that you will be returning to a your "base class" result and then extend its functionality.

The following sections of code will show how to construct a base class with private and public variables, and the do 2 levels of inheritance.

**Base Object**

```
//Base Object
var Animal = function(spec) {

    //This is our output object
    //Everything provided from 'spec' and
    //everything not addded to 'that' will
    //be 'private'. Everything added to
    //'that' is 'public'.
    var that = {};

    //Private Methods
    function extend(obj1,obj2) {
        for(var key in obj2) {
            obj1[key] = obj2[key];
        }
    }

    //Private Variables
    var defaults = {
        name : 'Default Name',
        food : 'Default Food',
        saying : 'Default Saying',
    }

    extend(defaults,spec);

    //Public Methods
    that.name = function() {
        return defaults.name;
    }

    that.eats = function() {
        if(typeof(defaults.food) === 'string') {
            return defaults.food;
        } else if(typeof(defaults.food) === 'object') {
            return defaults.food.join(', ');
        }
    }

    that.says = function() {
        return defaults.saying;
    }

    return that;
}

var myAnimal = Animal();       //Create a new instance
alert(myAnimal.name());        //Alerts 'Default Name'
alert(myAnimal.eats());        //Alerts 'Default Food'
alert(myAnimal.says());        //Alerts 'Default Saying'
alert(myAnimal.saying);        //Alerts 'undefined'
//alert(myAnimal.extend());    //Has No Method Error

var myAnimal2 = Animal({       //Create a new instance using a spec
    name : 'Mike',
    food : ['Chicken','Duck'],
    saying : 'Rawr',
});    
alert(myAnimal2.name());        //Alerts 'Mike'
alert(myAnimal2.eats());        //Alerts 'Chicken, Duck'
alert(myAnimal2.says());        //Alerts 'Rawr'
```

**Inheritance**

```
//Inheritance Object
var Mammal = function(spec) {

    //Private Methods

    //Have to redefine this since
    //I decided to use this as an
    //example of a private method
    function extend(obj1,obj2) {
        for(var key in obj2) {
            obj1[key] = obj2[key];
        }
    }

    //Private Variables
    //New list of defaults
    var defaults = {
        name : 'Mammal',
        attributes : ['fur'],
    }

    extend(defaults,spec);

    //Inherrit from our Animal Object
    //Use Mammal defaults
    var that = Animal(defaults);


    that.attributes = function() {
        if(typeof(defaults.attributes) === 'string') {
            return defaults.attributes;
        } else if(typeof(defaults.attributes) === 'object') {
            return defaults.attributes.join(', ');
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return that;
}

//Second-Level Inheritance
var Cat = function(spec) {

    //Private Methods

    //Have to redefine this since
    //I decided to use this as an
    //example of a private method
    function extend(obj1,obj2) {
        for(var key in obj2) {
            obj1[key] = obj2[key];
        }
    }

    //Private Variables
    //New list of defaults
    var defaults = {
        name : 'Cat',
        saying : 'Meow',
        food : ['fish','birds','frogs','MeowMix'],
        fur_color : 'Default Fur Color',
        attributes : ['fur','claws','crazy eyes','long tail'],
    }

    extend(defaults,spec);

    //Inherrit from our Mammal Object
    //We use our defaults for the cat
    var that = Mammal(defaults);

    that.fur_color = function() {
        return defaults.fur_color; 
    }

    that.purr = function(n) {
        var str = '';

        for(var i=0;i<n;i++) {
            if(i === 0) {
                str = 'p-';
            } else if(i === n-1) {
                str += 'r';
            } else {
                str += 'r-';
            }
        }

        return str
    };

    return that;
}


var myMammal = Mammal();
alert(myMammal.name());        //Alerts Mammal
alert(myMammal.attributes());  //Alerts 'fur'

var myCat = Cat();
alert(myCat.name());            //Alerts Cat
alert(myCat.says());            //Alerts Meow

var toonces = Cat({
    name : 'Toonces the Driving Cat',
    food : ['Whiskas','ham'],
    saying : 'Meeeooooowww',
    fur_color : 'Black',
    attributes : [ 
        'Can Drive a Car', 'Claws',
        'fur','crazy eyes','long tail',
        'Steals Hub Caps',
    ],
});

alert(toonces.name());            //Alerts 'Toonces the Driving Cat'
alert(toonces.says());            //Alerts 'Meeooooowww'
alert(toonces.eats());            //Alerts 'Whiskas, ham'
alert(toonces.fur_color());       //Alerts 'Black'
alert(toonces.attributes());      //Alerts 'Can Drive a Car, Claws,
                                  //fur, crazy eyes, long tail,
                                  // Steals Hub Caps',
alert(toonces.purr(5));           //Alerts 'p-r-r-r-r'
```

**EDIT**:  I was alerted that I did not use the "prototype" object.  I did this, as to avoid HAVING to use the "new" operator, as mentioned in the text above.  For completeness, I will give an example using the prototype object below...

**Inheritance with the Prototype Object**

```
//Building a class to use the prototype object
var Dog = function(spec) {

var that = this;

//Private Methods

    //Have to redefine this since
    //I decided to use this as an
    //example of a private method
    function extend(obj1,obj2) {
        for(var key in obj2) {
            obj1[key] = obj2[key];
        }
    }

    //Private Variables
    //New list of defaults
    var defaults = {
        name : 'Dog',
        saying : 'Woof',
        food : ['bacon'],
        fur_color : 'Default Fur Color',
        attributes : ['fur','Barks at Mailman'],
    }


    //Attach the properties of a Mammal to "self"
    this.self = new Mammal(defaults);

    //Add a function to get the name
    this.getName = function() {
        return that.self.name();
    }
}

//Extend the prototype
Dog.prototype.growl = "grrrrrrr";

//Make a new dog...HAVE TO CALL NEW HERE OR ELSE BAD THINGS CAN HAPPEN
d= new Dog();

alert(d.growl);            //Alerts 'grrrrrrr'
alert(d.getName());        //Alerts 'Dog'
alert(d.self.says());      //Alerts 'Woof'
```

Please feel free to ask me about any of this post.  Enjoy.

Comment: @Raynos, didn't use prototype as to avoid the 'new' operator.  If you check the edit, I gave an example of using the inheritance framework I set up and allowing you to build a class that is able to use the prototype object...

Comment: All I was saying is that it's simply not prototypical OO. Your using objects and closures. It's a solid example of an OO pattern, it's just not prototypical and doesnt answer the question

Comment: Yep, you are right..my bad on the misunderstanding initially...I prefer the closures personally...

Comment: and it's a solid option. I'm not saying this is a bad pattern at all. Of course you should remember that prototypes allow you to share methods and reduce your memory consumption and that's defiantly something not to forget about.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using a inheritance plugin model which attempts to combine the prototypical OO pattern with jQuery plugin pattern. Its posted in detail in my answer here: [attaching a class to a jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307918/attaching-a-class-to-a-jquery-object/6311706#6311706)

**Note:** Do not get turned away by mention of the word `Class`

Comment: Not what I'm looking for, it's class emulation. I'm starting to think we don't need inheritance either, just mix-ins.